# Can there be something incorrectly configured with my CPU?

Tags: windows-10, performance

This is a little weird, but I have noticed a BIG slowdown in some few areas of my PC. It performs well in games (i7-5820K, GTX 970, AAA Titles run with 60FPS+) and most other stuff, but a few things are INCREDIBLY slow, while they are nearly instant on my Surface Pro i7 2017. I have tried reinstalling affected applications, but not windows yet. Here are a few things that are wrong:

1. Opening Office apps takes way longer than it should
2. If you go into the Word formula editor and press on one of the tabs with different symbols like Matrices, different options will come up. The images for these can take up to a minute loading every time I reopen word.
3. Searches within some apps like Chrome or Adobe can take up to 5 times as long as on the Surface.

This doesn't seem right, is there any way I can check if everything is working as usual without reinstalling windows?

Comment: Do you have any third-party anti-virus software installed? What’s shown in Task Manager’s “Performance” tab when your system is slower than expected? Make sure to enable “Show graphs” in the left area to see all information. Could you perhaps elaborate on the search performance issue? It’s kind of out of place: In theory, it involves only memory access. How are you searching? How big are the documents you’re searching in?

Comment: @DanielB Only windows defender. 

About the search I am not sure anymore, the Chrome history results on both devices are actually not completely the same, so maybe I just have a longer history on my PC, even though it's supposed to sync everything.

If I do 1 and 2 my CPU usage rises to about 30%, no other significant changes.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to say for certain with the information provided, but it sounds to me like the problem is with disk rather then CPU.

I posit that when you are doing these operations the system is reading disk, which is relatively slow - especially compared to SSD.

There are a few things to look at -

If your system has an HDD light, see if it goes on solidly when the slowdowns occur.

1. Is there a hard drive in the system, and is it failing.  You may be able to get an indication from S.M.A.R.T info on the disk.
2. How much memory do you have and how many open programs?  You may well find your. system is using disk as memory (swapping) which greatly slows things down.
3. Disk fragmentation and/or nearly full disk - these can slow your disk speeds down dramatically and compound your IO problems.  Defragging the disk will reduce the problem.

Comment: I have a Samsung EVO 850 SSD with a capacity of 500GB (114 of 464GB avaible). I Scanned and Defragmented the disk and it showed no errors. SMART said OK for my drive.

I have 16 GB of Ram, rarely is more than 8 used. My swapfile.sys is 16MB big.

Comment: I did some copy pasting with an external HDD.

Copying onto my SSD it had a write speed of up to 250MB/s, on averarge around 100MB/s, bottlenecked by my HDD read speed.

Copying from SSD to HDD read speed on SSD was 100MB/s, bottlenecked by HDD write speed.

Comment: @Tomhawk  "My swapfile.sys is 16MB big" Was this a typo? Is it really 16MB or is it 16GB?

Comment: @Mokubai Swapfile.sys: 16,0 MB (16.777.216 Bytes)

Not a typo

Comment: `swapfile.sys` is for Metro Apps only. It’s not the same as `pagefile.sys`.